# Externally stop a running while loop

Tags: python, command-line, cmd, command, command-line-arguments

I have a cmd.Cmd class command line interpreter that, for example, initializes a self.counter = Counter().

After calling 'start', do_start() will call self.counter.start() and self.counter starts a while loop that counts from 0 to infinity.

Pseudocode example of Counter:

```
class Counter(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.number = 0
        self.running = False

    def start():
        self.running = True
        while self.running:
            self.number += 1

    def status():
        return self.number

    def stop():
        self.running = False
```

How can I call 'status' in my cmd.Cmd class (which calls do_status()) to get self.counter.status() which will give the current number that has been incremented?

And how can I call 'stop' in my cmd.Cmd class to get self.counter.stop() to stop the while loop.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that the `while` loop inside the *start* function is partial-infinite?

Comment: maybe need second thread to do it.

Comment: "Externally stop" - do you mean from another process or within the same process?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do something in parallel you must use threads or multiple processes like this:

```
import threading

from time import sleep


class Counter(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.number = 0
        self.running = False

    def start(self):
        self.running = True
        while self.running:
            self.number += 1
            # add sleep to prevent blocking main thread by this loop
            sleep(0.1)

    def status(self):
        return self.number

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False


class Cmd(object):
    t = None
    counter = None

    def start(self):
        self.counter = Counter()
        self.t = threading.Thread(target=self.counter.start)
        self.t.start()

    def do_status(self):
        return self.counter.status()

    def stop(self):
        self.counter.stop()
        # waiting while thread with Counter will finish
        self.t.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cmd = Cmd()
    print "Starting counter"
    cmd.start()
    sleep(5)
    print cmd.do_status()
    sleep(2)
    print cmd.do_status()
    cmd.stop()
    print "Counter was stopped"
```

Output will be:

```
Starting counter
50
70
Counter was stopped
```

But if you want to be able communicate with Counter from different application then you must learn about [sockets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) .

Answer (score 0):

if `cmd` is an instance of `Cmd` and your using an *instance method*:

Send the instance to `Counter`:

```
def __init__(self, cmd):
    self.number = 0
    # self.running = False # removed - use self.cmd.status() for control
    self.cmd = cmd
```

Control `while` using `self.cmd`:

```
def start():
    while self.cmd.status():
        self.number += 1
```

I expect `self.cmd.status()` to be blocking (expecting user input, or something like that).